# paginate the list in php

Tags: php, html, css

i have this php code that fetches images from the database using the userid, then displays all the images in a list form. im trying to paginate the images, in a limit of 5 items per page. but the code is showing only the first page,  without a link to the other pages. here's my php code

```
<?php
        include 'connect.php';


            $Category = " ";
            $query = "SELECT Img_dir, Caption, Category FROM images WHERE Category = '". $_REQUEST['Category'] ."' AND user_id = '". $_SESSION['user_id'] ."' LIMIT 0,5";


            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);


            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $image = $row["Img_dir"];
                $Caption= $row["Caption"];
                $Category = $row["Category"];
                    echo "<dl>";

                    echo "<dd>$Category &nbsp&nbsp <img src='base64_encode($image)' />&nbsp&nbsp $Caption<dd>";

                    echo "</dl>";
                    }
            //number of total pages available
            $results_per_page = 10;

            $number_of_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);

            echo $number_of_pages = ceil($number_of_results / $results_per_page);
            echo "<br>"; echo "<br>";
            for($r=1;$r<=$number_of_pages;$r++)
            {
                ?><a href="dashboard.php?page=<?php echo $r;?>" style="text-decoration:none"><?php echo $r." "; ?></a><?php 
            }
?>
```

Comment: `filter/display only images in the a certain category` - well we would need more information about your Database to do that.  Plus you really should read about prepared statements. `WHERE user_id = ? AND category = ?`  If you used PDO instead of MySqli, you could do `->fetch(PDO::FETCH_GROUP)` which would give you the structure you need.  As it is you'll have to build it in a foreach loop.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix here's my db  $query = "insert into images (Category,Caption,Img_dir,user_id) values ('$Category','$Caption','$image',$user_id)";

Comment: Then just add `AND Category = somecategory`  to your select above.

Comment: Start and end the `<ul>` outside of your `while` loop

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix that worked! thanks, how do i paginate the list? any clues i've read on it but i wanted a simpler method

Comment: I would probably suggest using a plugin (Javascript) for the UI part of it.  Then you use Limit and Offset  in the SQL.

Comment: @kerbholz but if so how will i call the while loop?

Comment: in your SQL you can do Limit (return this many rows) and Offset (start on this row) - then it just takes a bit of math to multiply by the number of rows you want and the page your getting.  It's too generic (too broad), because you will/should use a plugin so you'll have to follow the examples they have.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

Change your query (use prepare statments):

```
$query = "SELECT Img_dir, Category FROM images WHERE user_id = ? AND Category = ? ";
```

As for the structure of your data.

```
$results = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
       $key = $row['Category'];
       if(!isset($results[$key]))  $results[$key] = [];

       $results[$key][] = $row['Img_dir '];  //['Category' => [Img_dir,Img_dir, ...]]
}
```

And your HTML. I would use a description list or `dl` as it has a nice place for the title:

```
  foreach($results as $Category => $image){
        echo "<dl>";
        echo "<dt>$Category</dt>";
        foreach($data as $row){
           echo "<dd><img src='base64_encode($image)' /><dd>";
        }
        echo "</dl>";
  }
```

Untested.

The order will probably be all wanky, so you can use `ksort` on it. Simply

```
  ksort($results);
```

Before the `foreach` loops.

Cheers.

Comment: Yea, you just use the wile loop to group by the category,  you can't output it tell you group all the rows.  If you used PDO (instead of mysqli) you could skip that part.  PDO has a PDO::GROUP_BY flag for `fetchAll` that does exactly what is in the while loop.  Well not exactly as it would have both the image and the category. where I just used the image in the inner array.  But it's close enough that it's workable.

Comment: like I said I would find a paging plugin you like and then see how it goes from their examples.  If you have questions on that you can always post another answer.  I cant really say what you need to do (besides limit and offset) because a lot depends on what plugin you use.

Comment: ive made a bit of progress, now im trying to paginate but my code is only displaying one page...about the plugin man i'm just reading between the lines